# How to use Handlebars in footer

Tags: bigcommerce

This problem happens with Stencil themes.

I have tried adding them into Javascript, placing them within a CDATA tag and inserting them straight into markup but without success.

Right now I am just testing with a simple function : {{concat value1="Burim" value2="Shala"}}​​

Comment: What result are you getting on the storefront? Something should show up even if it is causing errors or not successfully rendering.

Comment: @Alyss it just prints the output like this : "{{concat value1="Burim" value2="Shala"}}​​"

Comment: This feature is only just now rolling out, so it might not be enabled for your store yet. Have you verified this?

Comment: @Alyss how can I verify that ?

Comment: @Alyss NVM, for some reasons this is working now.